# NGINX: map and try_files not working

Tags: nginx, regex

i am using nginx to detect webp support in browser:

```
# Check if client is capable of handling webp
map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
       default "";
       "~*webp" ".webp";
}
```

this code works ok and assign .webp to $webp_suffix when client support image/webp

then few lines later i am using this variable in following config:

```
        location ~ ^/imgs/([0-9]*)/(.*?)(\..+)$ {
                add_header X-webp $webp_suffix;
                try_files /imgs/$1$webp_suffix /imgs/$1$3 =404;
        }
```

and it ALWAYS results in e404 even if both files exist.
Header X-webp is set to ".webp" so map is working fine.

What is more weird - if i swap order of try_files arguments from:

```
try_files /imgs/$1$webp_suffix /imgs/$1$3 =404;
```

to

```
try_files /imgs/$1$3 /imgs/$1$webp_suffix =404;
```

then it do work and sent file /imgs/$1$3 to the browser. How is it possible ? Am i missing something in this logic ?

EDIT1:
Complete nginx.conf to reproduce:

```
events {
    use           epoll;
    worker_connections  128;
}

http {

    # Check if client is capable of handling webp
    map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
           default "";
           "~*webp" ".webp";
    }

    server {
            listen      *:8888;
            server_name   test;
            root  /srv;

            location ~ ^/imgs/([0-9]*)/(.*?)(\..+)$ {
                    add_header X-webp $webp_suffix;
                    try_files /imgs/$1$webp_suffix /imgs/$1$3 =404;
            }

    }
}
```

EDIT2:
What is even more weird - if i change:

```
try_files /imgs/$1$webp_suffix /imgs/$1$3 =404;
```

to:

```
try_files /imgs/$1.webp /imgs/$1$3 =404;
```

then try_files works as expected (but we are not checking webp support in client now, simply assuming that it do support it). Please remember that:

```
add_header X-webp $webp_suffix;
```

in the same location results in added header:
X-webp .webp

so why /imgs/$1$webp_suffix does not work and /imgs/$1.webp do work ?

What i have tested:

1. $webp_suffix = ".webp" (tested and it works)
2. try_files /imgs/$1$webp_suffix /imgs/$1$3 =404 - does NOT work and return 404
3. try_files /imgs/$1.webp /imgs/$1$3 =404 - does work and return webp file
4. try_files /imgs/$1$3 /imgs/$1$webp_suffix =404 - does work and return jpg
   file

which makes no sense at all

EDIT3:

For test i am opening:
http://test:8888/imgs/10/whatever.jpg

Files /srv/imgs/10.jpg and /srv/imgs/10.webp do exist.

Comment: Assuming `$webp_suffix` equals to `.webp` your regex substitutions gives you `/imgs/123/test.jpg` -> `try_files /imgs/123.webp /imgs/123.jpg =404;`, is this what you expecting?

Comment: What files exist? We cannot debug your logic if we do not know the URL you are testing and the full pathname of the file you are attempting to retrieve.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Yes. As i wrote in EDIT2 - when i explicitly change $webp_suffix to ".webp" then it works. It looks like:

1) $webp_suffix = ".webp" (tested and it works),
2) /imgs/$1$webp_suffix  - does NOT work,
3) /imgs/$1.webp  - does work

which makes no sense at all

Comment: @RichardSmith added test url and absolute paths in EDIT3

Comment: `/imgs/10/whatever` does not match your regex, it is `/imgs/10/whatever.anything` that does.

Comment: @IvanShatsky: My mistake, but /imgs/10/whatever.jpg does not work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `try_files` statement is using numeric captures from the regular expression in the `location` statement. The problem with numeric captures is that they are overwritten whenever a regular expression is evaluated. The `map` contains a regular expression that is evaluated between the `location` and the `try_files` statements.

The solution is to use named captures:

For example:

```
location ~ ^/imgs/(?<prefix>[0-9]*)/(.*?)(?<suffix>\..+)$ {
    add_header X-webp $webp_suffix;
    try_files /imgs/$prefix$webp_suffix /imgs/$prefix$suffix =404;
}
```