# Nginx: Rewrite while preserving the path

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I want to set up a temporary redirect to another domain but I want to keep the path very similar.

Here's an example:

Request URL: `https://api.mydomain.com/uploads/default/logo.png`

Rewritten URL should be: `https://cdn.mydomain.com/default/logo.png`

I have set the rule like this but it isn't working:

```
{

    server api.mydomain.com

    location /uploads/(.*)$ {
           rewrite ^ $scheme://cdn.mydomain.com/$1 redirect;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some explanations why your rewrite solution was not working. `rewrite` directive treats its first parameter as regex. You are using `^` as regex (a very common approach to match any string), and after regex matching `$1` variable has an empty value because `^` regex pattern doesn't have any capture groups. So it comes that the previous `$1` variable value get lost. In opposite `return` directive doesn't treat any parameter as regex and `$1` variable value doesn't get altered.

What can you do to prevent loss of `$1` variable value? Here are another two possible solutions:

- Use [named capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) in `location` directive:

  ```
  {

      server api.mydomain.com

      location /uploads/(?<suffix>.*) {
          rewrite ^ $scheme://cdn.mydomain.com/$suffix redirect;
      }

      ...

  }
  ```
- Use `rewrite` directive in the `server` context instead of `location` one:

  ```
  {

      server api.mydomain.com

      rewrite ^/uploads/(.*) $scheme://cdn.mydomain.com/$1 redirect;

      ...

  }
  ```

Sometimes using numeric capture groups leads to errors that are very hard to track, see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1036804/nginx-map-and-try-files-not-working) question/answer for example.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.

It was very straightforward, I worked it out using redirect. (Though, could not make it work using rewrite)

Here's the updated config:

```
 location ~ ^/uploads/(.*)$ {
           return 302 $scheme://cdn.mydomain.com/$1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do FAST redirect instead of regex matching, simpliest I found working for my self is this config:

```
    location / { # Redirect all with full path and request string
            return      302 http://cdn.mydomain.com$uri$is_args$args;
    }
```

This means, that all requests to this host will be completelly redirected with full path and all request args.

Set code to 301 for permanent redirect.