# Using a part of the URI as a port number for nginx proxy_pass directive

Tags: nginx, proxy, rewrite

This is my nginx configuration :

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name sub.example.fr ;
        location ~ ^/ (123[0-9])$ { # regex work
                #rewrite ^/[0-9]{4}(.*)$ $1 last; # do not work, with last or break
                #proxy_pass http://localhost:$1/; # add slash not allow
                proxy_pass http://localhost:$1;
        }
}
```

I want to forward `https://sub.example.fr/1234` to `http://localhost:1234`, so I just want to extract port number, remove it from url and use it into proxy_pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your `^/(123[0-9])$` regex will match only `/1234` URI (or `/1230`, `/1231`, etc.) but not the `/1234/some/path` since you are using the `$` end-of-string anchor. I'm assuming it isn't an error but a design solution. If it isn't, to match both `/1234` and `/1234/some/path` (but not something like `/12345`), you can use an alternation: `^/(123[0-9])(?:/|$)` (I'm using a non-capture group `(?:...)` here, as it is considered to have slightly better performance than the capture group).

Your configuration have a whole bunch of various mistakes. Lets look over each one.

**Mistake #1: Incorrect `rewrite ... last;` usage.**

Indeed, you can't specify an URI for the `proxy_pass` upstream like you are trying to do with a trailing slash

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:$1/; # add slash not allow
```

inside regex matching locations (as well as inside named locations) and the only way to change the URI that will be passed to the backend is to use the `rewrite` directive. However the right way to change an URI inside the `location` block to process it later within the same location is to use `rewrite ... break;` since `rewrite ... last;` will force nginx to search a new location for the rewritten URI. That means we need to use the `break` flag for the `rewrite` directive:

```
rewrite ^/[0-9]{4}(.*)$ $1 break;
```

**Beware!** No directives from the [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) will be executed after `rewrite ... break;` (or simply `break;`) directive (**update**: after some testing, in opposite to what is said in the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite), turns out it is true only for [`break`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#break) directive but not the `rewrite ... break` one, at least for the OpenResty 1.17.8.2 based on nginx 17.8 core).

**Mistake #2: You should enquote any string containing curly brackets or they will be considered as nginx configuration block.**

Previous directive will give us the following error:

> nginx: [emerg] directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";"

To get rid of this error we need to enquote our regex pattern due to the curly brackets usage:

```
rewrite "^/[0-9]{4}(.*)$" $1 break;
```

**Mistake #3: Numbered captures are overwritten whenever regular expression is evaluated.**

Lets assume you have an URI of `/1234`:

```
location ~ ^/(123[0-9])$ {
    # Here the value of '$1' variable is "1234"
    rewrite "^/[0-9]{4}(.*)$" $1 break;
    # Here the value of '$1' variable is an empty string!
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$1; # There will be no port for 'proxy_pass' directive
}
```

You can save that `$1` value before the rewrite rule evaluates its own regular expression using [`set`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#set) directive:

```
location ~ ^/(123[0-9])$ {
    set $port $1;
    rewrite "^/[0-9]{4}(.*)$" $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$port;
}
```

or better use the [named capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html):

```
location ~ ^/(?<port>123[0-9])$ {
    rewrite "^/[0-9]{4}(.*)$" $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$port;
}
```

Sometimes there can be no other solution but to use named captures, an excellent example of such a situation is given at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1036804/nginx-map-and-try-files-not-working) thread.

**Mistake #4: Rewritten URI can't be an empty string.**

Again, lets assume you have an URI of `/1234`. After the rewrite rule an internal nginx [`$uri`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri) variable will have an empty value. That would lead to HTTP 500 Internal Server error, and in nginx error log you'll see the following error message:

> the rewritten URI has a zero length

To resolve that error just rewrite any URI to the `/`:

```
location ~ ^/(?<port>123[0-9])$ {
    rewrite ^ / break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$port;
}
```

If you'd need to serve any `/<port_number>/some/path` request like above, you should use the following location block to ensure your rewritten URI starts with a slash:

```
location ~ ^/(?<port>123[0-9])(?:/|$) {
    rewrite "^/\d{4}(?:/(.*))?" /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$port;
}
```

**Mistake #5: You need to specify a resolver when using variables with the `proxy_pass` directive.**

The above configuration is close to the working solution. However it is still non-workable, giving you HTTP 502 Bad Gateway error. You need to specify a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) when you are using variables with the `proxy_pass` directive and your upstream is specified by the domain name rather than IP address, otherwise you'll get the following error in your nginx error log:

> no resolver defined to resolve localhost

Generally you'd have to use something like

```
resolver 8.8.8.8;
location ~ ^/(?<port>123[0-9])$ {
    rewrite ^ / break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$port;
}
```

but since your upstream is `localhost`, you can specify its IP address instead of the domain name, this way you won't need that `resolver` directive at all:

```
location ~ ^/(?<port>123[0-9])$ {
    rewrite ^ / break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$port;
}
```

This configuration should be fully workable (at last). And once again, if you'd need to serve any `/<port_number>/some/path` request like above, you should use the following location block instead:

```
location ~ ^/(?<port>123[0-9])(?:/|$) {
    rewrite "^/\d{4}(?:/(.*))?" /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$port;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is really impressive and very instructive, I hope it will help other people !

Comment: I made some (usefull, I hope) updates to the answer. Yes, the answer turned out to be quite detailed (isn't it worth to vote up? :) ), so to help other people find this information you can rename your question to something more common, like _Using a part of the URI as a port number for nginx proxy_pass directive_ or even more common _Using a part of the URI with nginx proxy_pass directive_.

Comment: One can also capture all the elements in `location` directive and leave out the `rewrite`.