# nginx reverse proxy IP_adr/1881 to localhost:1881 proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, rewrite, port, regex

I have read this post, and try many thing but i have issue with rewrite regex.
[here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1080986/using-a-part-of-the-uri-as-a-port-number-for-nginx-proxy-pass-directive)

I have many node.js processes as backends with always different port to access.

With Nginx reverse proxy in the same server i want to pass for exemple : `https://my-site/1881` to `http://127.0.0.1:1881` proxy_pass.

I can get 1881 from `my-site/1881` but i have always at the end `127.0.0.1:1881/1881`. Or Nginx error.
I don't knows exactly how to delete /1881 with `rewrite`.

That i tried :

```
location ~ ^/(?<port>\d\d\d\d)$ {            #Ok

        rewrite "^/[0-9]{4}(.*)$" $1 break;  #try and retry here
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$port;   #Ok
}
```

Thank you for your help, have a good day

Comment: i think / is missing on the end since else it will afaik a relatively url

Comment: No, i have always 127.0.0.1:1881/1881 :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I'm running with :

```
location ~ ^/(?<port>\d\d\d\d) {

rewrite "^/\d{4}/(.*)" /$1 break;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$port;
```

}

And working well but now not displaying any picture :-(