# Nginx reverse proxy reach my site but can't get pictures

Tags: nginx, port, regex, image

I've been struggling for 3 days with Nginx reverse proxy to realize i think, a easy thing.
I have to simply reach many backend node-red (nodeJS) application from Nginx but always, with different ports.

For the next, this my example :

```
Web client -> `https://ip_adr/1881/ui/` -> Nginx proxy_pass `http://127.0.0.1:1881/ui/` (app)
```

Backend app serves pictures on `http://127.0.0.1:1881/*.jpg`

---

1. I realise a static test with :

```
location / {
        #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1881;
}
```

`https://ip_adress/ui` in my browser running well with all app pictures.

2. With rewrite to forward the port from frontend to backend, dynamically :

   ```
   location ~ ^/(?<port>\d\d\d\d) {

       rewrite "^/\d{4}/(.*)" /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$port;
   ```

   }

With the regex, i extract port from ip_adr/1881 with `/(?<port>\d\d\d\d)`, and rewrite url without `/1881` but keeping eventualy `/path1/path2/...`

If i put `https://192.168.x.x/1881/ui/` in my browser everything good but WITHOUT pictures.

---

After many and many tests, my browser don't display any images, and the trace error log say me for all picture :

```
2022/03/10 01:01:36 [error] 50065#50065: *1224 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/schema_fire_EEU.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.29, server: exemple3.test.fr, request: "GET /schema_fire_EEU.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.1.53", referrer: "https://192.168.1.53/1881/ui/"
```

That is very incredible, if i put `https://192.168.x.x/1881/schema_fire_EEU.jpg`, i can display this image !!!

I think, there is a problem with slash ...

Someone can help me ?

Have a good day ;-)

Comment: Duplicate of [nginx reverse proxy IP\_adr/1881 to localhost:1881 proxy\_pass](https://serverfault.com/questions/1095645/nginx-reverse-proxy-ip-adr-1881-to-localhost1881-proxy-pass)

Comment: Sorry but, not the same ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of what you're saying the problem could be that the URI to which you are proxying it's not right.

If this "https://192.168.x.x/1881/schema_fire_EEU.jpg" works means that your service is exposing your image under "/", but the ProxyPass rule does not have the "/".

You could try with:

```
ProxyPass / http://ip:port
```

Have a nice day.
:)

Comment: Thank you but, rather ``proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$port/;`` ?

Comment: ProxyPass is Apache Syntax not Nginx

Comment: Ok, but i can't get any picture anymore