# Nginx returns 415 when using image_filter with webp

Tags: nginx

I have some jpg/png files that get resized in a location (with `image_filter` module) and it's working fine. But, I have also a `webp` version of some images and I want to serve the `webp` one if it exists. If not, the original `jpg/png` image should be served.

I'm using the following configuration:

```
map $http_accept $webp_suffix {
    default        "";
    "~image/webp"  "webp";
}

location ~ "/@s/(.*)(png|jpe?g)" {
    alias                       $BASE_PATH/$1;
    try_files                   $webp_suffix $2 $uri;

    image_filter                resize 1200 -;
    image_filter_jpeg_quality   80;
    image_filter_buffer         10M;
}
```

But nginx returns a `415 Unsupported Media Type` error when the webp version is found. If the `webp` file is missing, it serves the jpg/png file without any error. The Nginx version is **1.16.1**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NGINX: map and try\_files not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/1036804/nginx-map-and-try-files-not-working)

Comment: Besides you are using the `try_files` directive incorrectly, there is one more caveat using `map` derived variables inside the regular expression location with the numbered capture groups. An explanation and a working example are given here: [NGINX: map and try_files not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/1036804/nginx-map-and-try-files-not-working).

Comment: @IvanShatsky I changed the numeric variables to named variables but I see no difference. Still getting `415 Unsupported Media Type`.

Comment: It might be that `image_filter` reads the filename from `$uri` variable, and it thinks the image is JPEG.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen As described in the docs, the WEBP should be supported in image_filter but for some reason, it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess it supports the WEBP format properly when the actual request URL contains `.webp` extension. In your configuration, the request URL is `.png` or `.jpg`, whichever is the original extension. Therefore `image_filter` tries to access the image using wrong decoder. It might not be possible to combine the mapping and `image_filter` modules.

Comment: do you resolved your problem with nginx and webp?
I have the same problem :)
centos 7 too, epel nginx 1.20
i trying nginx repo with nginx 1.21 but no effect.

Comment: @drboczek Unfortunately no, I couldn't. Instead, I used our CDN provider WEBP conversion feature which is available on Cloudflare too.

Answer (score 0):

A more streamlined configuration for this is:

```
map $http_accept $webpuri {
    ~image/webp    $uri.webp;
    default        "";
}

location ~ \.png|jpe?g$ {
    try_files    $webpuri $uri;
    ...
}
```

Your `root` directive is used here to get the full path to files on your filesystem.

Comment: I don't get where is the difference. I used `alias` instead of `root` for addressing the file path on the filesystem.

Comment: The code above does not use regular expressions to split the URI into filename base part and extension, which is quite hacky. Instead we take the full file path and add `.webp` after the whole path.

Comment: I think the `image_filter` caused the problem, not the regular expression. If I remove the image_filter, my own code works. So obviously there is nothing wrong with addressing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but too long to be a comment.

@TeroKilkanen [made an assumption](https://serverfault.com/questions/1083701/nginx-returns-415-when-using-image-filter-with-webp#comment1414806_1083701):

> It might be that `image_filter` reads the filename from `$uri` variable, and it thinks the image is JPEG.

Lets check out if it is true. Fortunately, nginx is an open source software and the source code of `ngx_http_image_filter_module` is available [here](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.c).

The main `ngx_http_image_body_filter` function [started](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.c#L291) at line 291. Let's look at the beginning:

```c
    ...
    switch (ctx->phase) {

    case NGX_HTTP_IMAGE_START:

        ctx->type = ngx_http_image_test(r, in);

        conf = ngx_http_get_module_loc_conf(r, ngx_http_image_filter_module);

        if (ctx->type == NGX_HTTP_IMAGE_NONE) {

            if (conf->filter == NGX_HTTP_IMAGE_SIZE) {
                out.buf = ngx_http_image_json(r, NULL);

                if (out.buf) {
                    out.next = NULL;
                    ctx->phase = NGX_HTTP_IMAGE_DONE;

                    return ngx_http_image_send(r, ctx, &out);
                }
            }

            return ngx_http_filter_finalize_request(r,
                                              &ngx_http_image_filter_module,
                                              NGX_HTTP_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
        }
        ...
```

We see it is the `ngx_http_image_test` function that is responsible for the decision about image validity. Let's look at that function ([started](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.c#L423) at line 423):

```c
static ngx_uint_t
ngx_http_image_test(ngx_http_request_t *r, ngx_chain_t *in)
{
    u_char  *p;

    p = in->buf->pos;

    if (in->buf->last - p < 16) {
        return NGX_HTTP_IMAGE_NONE;
    }

    ngx_log_debug2(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, r->connection->log, 0,
                   "image filter: \"%c%c\"", p[0], p[1]);

    if (p[0] == 0xff && p[1] == 0xd8) {

        /* JPEG */

        return NGX_HTTP_IMAGE_JPEG;

    } else if (p[0] == 'G' && p[1] == 'I' && p[2] == 'F' && p[3] == '8'
               && p[5] == 'a')
    {
        if (p[4] == '9' || p[4] == '7') {
            /* GIF */
            return NGX_HTTP_IMAGE_GIF;
        }

    } else if (p[0] == 0x89 && p[1] == 'P' && p[2] == 'N' && p[3] == 'G'
               && p[4] == 0x0d && p[5] == 0x0a && p[6] == 0x1a && p[7] == 0x0a)
    {
        /* PNG */

        return NGX_HTTP_IMAGE_PNG;

    } else if (p[0] == 'R' && p[1] == 'I' && p[2] == 'F' && p[3] == 'F'
               && p[8] == 'W' && p[9] == 'E' && p[10] == 'B' && p[11] == 'P')
    {
        /* WebP */

        return NGX_HTTP_IMAGE_WEBP;
    }

    return NGX_HTTP_IMAGE_NONE;
}
```

I think it is pretty clear that the above function analyze first 16 bytes of the buffer trying to find one of the four known signatures. So the problem isn't related to the `$uri` variable value.

What can be the cause? Well, `ngx_http_image_filter_module` documentation [says](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_image_filter_module.html) the following:

> This module utilizes the [libgd](http://libgd.org/) library. It is recommended to use the latest available version of the library.
>
> The WebP format support appeared in version 1.11.6. To transform images in this format, the `libgd` library must be compiled with the WebP support.

Maybe the problem is in your nginx build. Check the WebP and `image_filter` compatibility without any additional URI transformations, something like

```
location ~ \.webp$ {
    image_filter                resize 1200 -;
    image_filter_jpeg_quality   80;
    image_filter_buffer         10M;
}
```

and then requesting the existing WebP file explicitly. If you'll still get a `415 Unsupported Media Type` error, the problem is most likely in your nginx build.

Comment: I had tested the `image_filter` with `webp` and the same `415 Unsupported Media Type` problem existed. So there is likely a problem with `libgd`. 
I had installed my `nginx` from the official yum repository. Should I build it manually with any custom configuration?

Comment: What linux distro are you using?

Comment: It's a Centos 7 server.

Comment: And one more question, what repo are you using? Is it nginx official repository or EPEL or something else?

Comment: It's the EPEL repo.